# Asserting on extended information from Nagios's check_mysql

Tags: mysql, monitoring, nagios

I'm running the `check_mysql` plugin using NRPE on a remote DB-server, and while I can get satisfactory data on whether or not the server *process* is working as needed, I see that the plugin outputs a lot more info:

```
user@server:/etc/nagios# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mysql -H localhost -P 3306 -u nagios -psnip
Uptime: 112398  Threads: 5  Questions: 10921804  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 4408  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 416  Queries per second avg: 97.170|Connections=137481c;;; Open_files=0;;; Open_tables=416;;; Qcache_free_memory=1031832;;; Qcache_hits=0c;;; Qcache_inserts=0c;;; Qcache_lowmem_prunes=0c;;; Qcache_not_cached=9427651c;;; Qcache_queries_in_cache=0;;; Queries=10921805c;;; Questions=10917613c;;; Table_locks_waited=0c;;; Threads_connected=5;;; Threads_running=1;;; Uptime=112398c;;;
```

Which makes me think that I can assert on things like the number of threads or slow queries to generate alert states.

The question is, how do I do that? The plugin's `-w` and `-c` parameters only deal with master-slave clock drift, but none of the other parameters.
Do I need to whip up some custom shell script to parse the output then return its own output? Or is there a built in facility in Nagios Core to do that sort of munging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided the best course of action would be to whip up a custom bit of scripting following the plugin specs, and do some string munging with `awk`. For future reference (*caveat implementor*):

```
#! /bin/bash

parse_mysql_output(){
    METRIC=`/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mysql -H localhost -P 3306 -u nagios -p[REDACTED] | grep -shoP "${METRIC_NAME}: ([\d.]+)" | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}'`
    if (($(echo "$METRIC <= $WARNING_THRESHOLD" | bc -l))); then
        echo "OK - $METRIC_NAME: $METRIC"
        exit 0
    fi

    if (($(echo "$METRIC > $WARNING_THRESHOLD" | bc -l))); then
        if (($(echo "$METRIC <= $CRITICAL_THRESHOLD" | bc -l))); then
            echo "WARNING - $METRIC_NAME: $METRIC"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi

    if (($(echo "$METRIC >= $CRITICAL_THRESHOLD" | bc -l))); then
        echo "CRITICAL - $METRIC_NAME: $METRIC"
        exit 2
    fi

    echo "INDETERMINATE STATE - $METRIC_NAME: $METRIC"
    exit 3
}

if [[ -z "$1" || -z "$2" || -z "$3" ]]
then
    echo "Missing parameters! Syntax: ./`basename $0` metric warning_threshold critical_threshold"
    exit 3
else
    METRIC_NAME=$1
    WARNING_THRESHOLD=$2
    CRITICAL_THRESHOLD=$3
fi

parse_mysql_output
```

In the intended use-case, you'd call this via a custom command in the NRPE config, and pass the metrics and thresholds. Before calling, you'd need to change the connection as required for your installation.

Feedback and comments welcome.